# Is there an algorithm to find nearby points using only polar coordinates?

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

Suppose I have a vector of points as polar coordinates.

Suppose one of those points acts as a probe for which I want to find all the other points within a certain distance.

Is there an algorithm to do this without converting them to Cartesian form?

Comment: does euclidean algorithm work for you?

Comment: You can calculate the radii and arc that correspond to the segment that fully contains your point and search radius, then examine all the other points within those boundaries.  You eventually, of course, have to somehow calculate the distances between those points and yours.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for the distance for polar coordinates. You can find the formula in this [link](http://math.ucsd.edu/~wgarner/math4c/derivations/distance/distancepolar.htm).

The distance between points (r1, a1) and (r2, a2) is:

```
D = sqrt(r1*r1 + r2*r2 - 2*r1*r2*cos(a1-a2))
```

Answer (score 2):

Be careful, if you plan to scale up your algorithm to many points, probing for points nearby is better done using a *spatial index*. I'm not aware of the existence of spatial indexes using polar coordinates, and I'm sure they would be a bit complex to implement/use. So if you have:

- lots of points,
- probe more frequently than moving points,

ask yourself the question whether you should use Cartesian coordinates and a spatial index.

Do the math yourself according to your typical use case:

1. Using cartesian alongside polar coordinates:

   - Converting polar to cartesian is done only when a point moves, and involve two trigonometric functions;
   - Finding points nearest than a certain distance to another point may be done in O(1) time (depending on the average distance, the size of the spatial index, the number of points...), and does not involve anything other than adds/multiplies (not even square roots, you compare the distance squared).
2. Using polar coordinates only:

   - Scanning for all points w/o spatial index is O(n);
   - This involves one trigonometric function per comparison (thus *n* trig calls per probe).

Be aware that trigs are bloody expensive in computation time.

Comment: Hi, how many points are lots of points? And I know the device that's doing the computing is important so lets say that is a mobile device like iPhone 4 or something like that. Thanks.

Comment: How many really depends on your CPU, language, etc... You have to prototype to really know. Usually the question is not how many *on average*, but if there is a bound on *how large your set can grow*..

Comment: I think it's better to call data as less as possible by filtering them  first by using city/post-code or even type of data like restaurant or coffee shop and etc. Or even limit the data in nearby, if there is a million points within 5km try to sort them by rank or something because nobody's going to look that much data on a mobile. Thanks, that growing set you mentioned is the key.

Comment: That's just the typical use case of a spatial index: to return in `O(1)` the list of points in a given radius around a base point. Filtering on postcode is wrong as you can sit on a postcode limit and have a point just nearby with another postcode. Filtering w/o index is still `O(n)`, a correct spatial index is `O(1)`, at worst `O(log(n))`.

Comment: So lets say that I've already have the distance from user's current location and that item (direct point to point not by route or traffic-wise), is it ok to just put them in a loop and check if they are within that distance by a simple <> operation and a IF statement? Is that a ok approach for nearby in this situation?