# Computing the distance between two points in polar coordinates using floating-point

Tags: floating-point, language-agnostic, ieee-754, numerical-analysis

When the coordinates of two points in the plane are provided in polar form as `r1, a1` and `r2, a2`, where `r1, r2, a1, a2` are floating-point numbers, and the goal is to compute the distance between the two points as a floating-point number, it may be tempting to use the mathematical formula below:

```
D = sqrt(r1*r1 + r2*r2 - 2*r1*r2*cos(a1-a2))
```

This formula can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9344938/139746) and several other answers on StackOverflow. The link to the source provided in the linked answer is dead, but you find this formula in a lot of mathematical resources, for instance [this website](https://socratic.org/questions/what-is-the-formula-for-the-distance-between-two-polar-coordinates).

As a floating-point formula, this formula has a number of undesirable properties, listed below by decreasing seriousness. In short, my question is: what is a better formula to compute the distance `D` in the conditions stated above?

### A/ `sqrt` is applied to a negative number when `r1 = r2` and `r1*r1` is subnormal

When `r1*r1` is subnormal and `r1 = r2`, the rounding of `r1*r1` is different from the rounding of `2*r1*r2`. At one extreme of this spectrum of counter-examples, `r1*r1` is zero and `2*r1*r2` is nonzero. At the other extreme, `r1*r1` is subnormal and gets rounded somewhat brutally downwards, and `2*r1*r2` is normal and gets rounded less brutally. Either way, the expression inside `sqrt` ends up being negative and the result of the floating-point formula for `D` is `NaN`.

Example values for double-precision:

```
  double r1 = sqrt(DBL_MIN * DBL_EPSILON) * sqrt(0.45);
  double r2 = r1;
```

[Run it on Compiler Explorer.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/uFBzM9)

### B/ `sqrt` is applied to a negative number when `r1` is close to `r2` while different

When `r1` and `r2` are very close, the distance between the mathematical products `r1*r1` and `r1*r2` is very close to the distance between the mathematical products `r1*r2` and `r2*r2`. When this common distance corresponds to a small, odd number of half-ULPs, the situation can arise that the floating-point multiplication `r1*r1` rounds down, `r1*r2` rounds up, and `r2*r2` rounds down again. In these conditions, again, the commonly-seen formula takes the square root of a negative number.

Example values for double-precision:

```
  double r1 = 0x1.1c71c71c71d3fp0;
  double r2 = 0x1.1c71c71c71dcbp0;
```

[Run it on Compiler Explorer.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/vdcz7X)

### C/ When `r1` is close to `r2`, the subtraction magnifies the approximations that take place in the multiplications

This is in fact a more benign symptom of the same root causes for issues A/ and B/. When `r1` is very close to `r2`, the phenomenon known as [catastrophic cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance) occurs. The relative accuracy of the subtraction is terrible (for instance, with `a1 = a2` and `r1` close to `r2`, rounding during the multiplications can make the result of the subtraction 0.0 although the optimal answer, `fabs(r1 - r2)`, was representable and infinitely more accurate in relative terms. Note that the absolute accuracy of the result is of the order of the ULP of `r1` and `r2`, and this may still be fine.

### D/ Overflow when the magnitude of `r1` or `r2` is too large

If only `r1*r1` or `r2*r2` overflows, the result is computed as `+inf` which may not be the best representable approximation of the mathematical distance.

If `r1*r2` overflows, then the result of the subtraction is `NaN`, and the distance is therefore computed as `NaN`.

---

Issues A/ and B/ render meaningless a result that did not have to be, and can be solved by computing `dq > 0 ? sqrt(dq) : 0` instead of `dq`. For inputs that caused them, this change makes the answer `0.0` instead. This result has an infinite relative error, as do the results for other inputs, because this does not solve issue C/.

Issue D/ can be solved by scaling if the programmer expects that the computation will be used in conditions that trigger it. For that matter, issue A/ could also be solved by scaling, but that would not solve issue B/.

It is likely that a full solution that solves all issues A-D will involve more computations. There may exist several sweet spots that solve only some of the issues, or that solve issue C/ more or less thoroughly, computing distances that are accurate to 10 ULP, or 3, or 1. Any solution that is improves over the starting point is worthy of an answer.

Guillaume Melquiond already pointed out off-site that the formula below is equivalent to the original in mathematical terms, and it obviously escapes issues A/ and B/ since the argument of the square root is a sum of nonnegative terms:

```
D = sqrt((r1-r2)*(r1-r2) + 2*r1*r2*(1 - cos(a2-a1)))
```

In this solution, the catastrophic cancellation occurs in `1 - cos(a2-a1)`, so some aspects of issue C/ remains (although the computation with this formula is optimal for `a1=a2` and `r1` close to `r2`, as then `r1-r2` and `cos(a2-a1)` are exact). The situation with respect to issue D/ is improved but there remain cases where the results was representable as a finite value and the formula computes `+inf`.

Comment: Even if it sounds dumb what about `cartesian_distance(pol2cart(p1),pol2cart(p2))`? if cartesian distance use hypot() for overflow/underflow protection and pol2cart use sincos(), that's not mush more costly, doesn't it remove much of the problems?

Comment: @aka.nice This is a very interesting approach. I almost pointed out the analogy with the `hypot` standard function for cartesian distance, but the question was long enough already.

Comment: For avoiding intermediate overflow and underflow, I'd suggest scaling `r1` and `r2` by the same power of the radix (presuming radix 2, but radix 10 could work similarly) so that after scaling, the larger of the two is between `0.5` and `1.0` in absolute value. Then it should be easy to show that the computation with the scaled values is safe from both underflow and overflow, and underflow or overflow will only happen as a result of a final reverse scaling. You'd need to special case `r1 = 0.0` and/or `r2 = 0.0` first, of course. BTW, do you need/want to allow negative `r1` or `r2`?

Comment: @MarkDickinson I should have said that `r1` and `r2` were nonnegative. I'm still hesitating to place restrictions on `a1` and `a2`.

Comment: The sign of `r1` and `r2` isn't a big deal, I think; the case where both are negative is trivially easy (just ignore the signs), and if they have opposite signs then you end up wanting to compute `1 + cos(a2 - a1)` instead of `1 - cos(a2-a1)`, and again that's expressible as twice a simple square. The real challenge is in computing something like `2 * sin((a1 - a2)/2)` accurately over all possible `a1` and `a2`, and indeed restrictions on the magnitudes of `a1` and `a2` would help massively there.

Comment: ... and the solution there is not to compute `sin((a1 - a2)/2)` as written, but to expand it out as `sin(a1/2)cos(a2/2) - cos(a1/2)sin(a2/2)`, effectively making use of your libm's ability to reduce large values modulo `2*pi` (assuming that it produces accurate results for `cos(large)` and `sin(large)`, and therefore has such an ability). It would still be tough to get good ulp accuracy in the case where (1) r1 is very close (perhaps even equal) to r2, and (2) a1 is very close to a2, but only *after reduction* modulo 2*pi.

Comment: @MarkDickinson If you are going to post an answer with a hard bound guarantee expressed in ULPs, you are allowed to assume that the inputs of the problem are `r1` and `r2` positive floating-point values and `angdiff` the angle difference as a floating-point value.

Comment: See if adding parens one place fixes the problem:  `...2*(r1*r2)*cos...`

Comment: @RickJames It doesn't. Now `r1*r2` overflows or the multiplication of that by `2` does. You can try to be cute and place `(1 - cos(a2-a1))` as the first factor since it's always less than 1, but that in itself does not solve entirely the problem that you get `+inf` when a better result could be represented as a finite float. Note that the problem is entirely solved in the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Let b = (a1-a2)/2 
then using
cos( a1-a2) = 1 - 2*sin(b)*sin(b)
D = sqrt( (r1-r2)*(r1-r2) + 4*r1*r2*sin(b)*sin(b))
```

This at least gets rid of square roots of negative numbers but would still problems with overflow.

Perhaps

```
x = 2*sqrt(r1)*sqrt(r2)*sin(b)
D = hypot( r1-r2, x)
```

would resolve that?

Comment: Note that while most users probably don't care, `a1-a2` is subject to overflow, loss of precision, etc. as well. For example if `a1` is near a multiple of 2pi larger than a few times 2**53, and `a2` is approximately pi, you'd compute the distance as if the points are at the same angle rather than opposite directions along the x-axis.

Comment: I'm not sure which “catastrophic cancellation” you refer to in the sentence “ But there's still the catastrophic cancellation”. Note that `r1` and `r2` are inputs of the problem and that the question is how to compute the most accurate distance given the exact value of `r1` and `r2`, and not what happens if `r1` and `r2` are themselves approximations of other values. In other words, if `r1` and `r2` are close in value, `r1-r2` is not a case of catastrophic cancellation. On the contrary, it is exact! (Sterbenz lemma)

Comment: With my current understanding, this answer contains the two algorithms that one should definitely use to compute polar coordinate distances, depending on whether one fears overflows or not. Note that if you never want `D` to be computed as `+inf` when a finite value would be a better answer, `x` should be computed as `sin(b)*2*sqrt(r1)*sqrt(r2)` in the second algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on this sort of numerical analysis but wanted to point out that these days there are computer programs that try to give a more "stable" version of your formula with respect to floating-point issues. One of the better ones is the so called Herbie system: https://herbie.uwplse.org/

They do have a web-demo, and when I plug-in your equation, it comes up with:

https://herbie.uwplse.org/demo/9c74ffee9d36a7f50669c498f99c86d1c0b4c837.f316bcef3de0492d34dcdbc4c663eb04d00305c4/graph.html

The above link has a ton more info about the translation it recommends. In case the web-link disappears, here's a screenshot of the final formula it proposes:

[image]

You can also get the same output in LaTeX or C. It makes a claim that the error has been reduced from 31.5 to 18.5; though I'm not sure what those numbers precisely mean. They do have a short-tutorial to get you started: https://herbie.uwplse.org/doc/latest/tutorial.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: This looks highly suspect to me. Supposing we ignore negative `r` values, that final `else` clause is suggesting that we use the formula `r1 - 1 . (cos(a1 - a2) .r2)` for *all* cases where `r1 > 5.81e-4`. That's an approximation that might be accurate for tiny `r2`, but is going to be massively different from the desired result as soon as `r2` is anything but tiny - it's a completely different (not mathematically equivalent) formula. The case for `r1 <= -0.0193` is similarly bad (it doesn't even vary with `a1` or `a2`!), but it's possible that the OP doesn't care about negative `r` values.

Comment: It's possible I didn't use their interface correctly; though I didn't really check the results for any sort of correctness. If you think the result is erroneous, I'm sure they'll be delighted to hear your thoughts: https://github.com/uwplse/herbie/issues

Comment: I've played with Herbie before and got similarly bad results; I think I did make a couple of bug reports, but I'm far from convinced that it's fit for purpose. Numerical analysts aren't going to be out of a job any time soon.

Answer (score 1):

The distance remains the same if we rotate the whole figure.
Using the pol2cart idea, we can have some variations like:

```
x1=r1 cos((a2-a1)/2),y1=-r1 sin((a2-a1)/2)
x2=r2 cos((a2-a1)/2),y2= r2 sin((a2-a1)/2)

dist = hypot((r2-r1) cos((a2-a1)/2),(r2+r1) sin((a2-a1)/2)))
```

If angles are unbounded rather than properly reduced, then it's necessary to develop further the sin/cos formulas making this formulation not so useful...
`r2+r1` might also overflow, in which case we could apply simple scaling like `2*hypot((r1/2+r2/2)...)`

Comment: Except, *in general*, you can't rotate the whole figure without catastrophic loss. The difference `a2-a1` might not be representable with **any** significant bits. :-)

Comment: Well, I guess you could do it by rolling your own argument reduction first, or by `atan(tan(...))` or similar. But that's already well beyond the cost you want this operation to have.

Comment: @R.. I should have phrased the question by saying that the inputs of the problem were `r1` and `r2`, the radial coordinates of each point as positive floating-point numbers and `angdiff` the difference between the angles as a floating-point number. This would not make any existing answer lose in generality (although it would mess up notations). I may edit the question and all answers to prevent future readers to be distracted by this aspect.